# pip environment markers with specific wheel files in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Environment markers in pip requirements.txt files have been working fairly well for me until now....

I have locally built wheels that I would like to explicitly specify in the requirements.txt file. This works well, except that for some reason, environment markers on those packages seem to be ignored.

E.g.:
This line works with pypi as expected, and limits the package installation to python3.4:

```
PySide; python_version == '3.4'
```

And this line works with the local wheel, but of course, installs regardless of the python version:

```
/foo/bar/PySide-1.2.4-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

So I would expect this line to be the solution, but it behaves as though the environment marker doesn't exist:

```
/foo/bar/PySide-1.2.4-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl; python_version == '3.4'
```

I've been unable to find any clarification about the expected behaviour in either the pip documentation or on-line. This seems like it would be straight-forward and consistent with the rest of the pip use-model.  Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug, so I suggest you try reporting it as such. Found a very similar case [here](http://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3254).